# WCF - "Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found." but only from one client

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that is working great in production except for one new instance of a client that is unable to communicate with the service.

The WCF service runs over https on .Net 4.0 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 system. All clients are .Net 4.0 or higher (these are not under my control/config).

Enabling WCF Tracing in the service when this one client fails to connect shows this error:

"Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found."

I have verified the exact same URL and WSDL are used by working clients and the one nonworking client. I CAN view the service information site and WSDL over https using a web browser.

I am suspecting a possible SSL/TLS negotiation failure, but wanted to check to see if others are familiar with this particular type of situation.

Here is my service web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INamedService">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="NamedService.NamedServiceService">
        <endpoint address="/NamedServiceService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="https://my.domain.com/NamedServiceService" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INamedServiceService" contract="NamedServiceService.INamedServiceService" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Did you figure it out? Having same issue

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a typo in your endpoint bindingConfiguration:

```
bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INamedServiceService"
```

Your binding is named: BasicHttpBinding_INamedService not BasicHttpBinding_INamedServiceService

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INamedService">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

not sure what your contract name is but it does have ServiceService in it too, might want to double check that out.

Comment: Thanks! I did a text replace in the service and interface names in my post to protect the innocent. The production binding names do work with almost all clients.

Comment: @Everett ah,okay well then, it really sounds like an issue with the client config. With out seeing what the client is doing, I suspect it will be hard determine the error. The only security I see is that the service is over HTTPS. If there was a problem with that, I suspect the error would be different. There could be proxy, firewall issues on their end, no telling. They may not have their web.config set up properly. Essentially the error is indicating that there is not endpoint that matches what the client is trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the same project, why is your service implement and service interface namespace different? There may be some spelling mistakes in your configuration. I suggest you check it carefully.

> name="NamedService.NamedServiceService"
>   contract="NamedServiceService.INamedServiceService"

Besides, try to use the following configuration to set up https protocol.

```
<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myhttpsbinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="myhttpbinding">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.